# TextView will not fill parent width

Tags: android, css

I have a table layout, with two rows.

The width of the Textview will not fill the entire width of the Table row however it fills the height just fine.

The table row is the correct size, filling half the height and the entire width.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: when using `layout_weight`, you need to set either the `layout_width` or the `layout_height` of that view to `0dp`. So change the `TableRow`s from `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add to your textview

> android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: why it required? then what will be difference between layout_weight and layout_span? layout_span will also occupy full space then no need to add layout_weight. is it not?

Comment: To join two or more column as one then we give number of column to join as 'x' value in layout_span = 'x'
If the number of column is unknown what we do.

In layout_weight you can specify a size ratio between multiple views to occupy

Comment: Can you help me to understand `android:shrinkColumns` attribute? I didn't found any useful example, when I try to ask the question on this `How android:shrinkColumns works in TableLayout` SO warn me that this type of question has already downvoted or closed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TableRow>
```

or change layout size to `fill_parent`

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```